# How to simulate Lego Mindstorms programs written in C#?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms

I am going to do some programming for Lego Mindstorms in C# using

http://www.mindsqualls.net/

and have a question. Is there any good simulator to see result of my program without uploading the code to the robot?

Comment: I'm not sure a simulator would be able to properly mimic the physical aspects of a robot; but it's an intriguing idea. Sadly, I don't know if anyone has ever done this.

Comment: I think you might be able to do something like this with Microsoft Robotics Studio. Here is a video that appears to do what you want: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcETVcobqfc

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there are no simulators for Lego Mindstorms in C# that fit your requirements. As Sebastian Wahl mentioned, Microsoft Robotics Studio is probably your best bet. Hopefully there will be a tool like this in the future :)